# How to implement box-shadow like effect in IE8 - quirks mode

Tags: internet-explorer-8, css

This might just be an impossible question, but I want to give it a try: so how can I have a `box-shadow` like effect in `IE8` qirks mode. (Don't ask me why but we are not using `DOCTYPE`s).

I've already tried [PIE](http://css3pie.com/), and that is not an option for me.

Comment: you can use background images for shadows

Comment: I know but that's a pain ... however if there is no other option I have to use that. Anyway developing for IE8 is a pain in itself :|

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS Box shadow not working in IE6 and IE7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857022/css-box-shadow-not-working-in-ie6-and-ie7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a filter statement directly, rather than having PIE automatically generate one for you.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533086(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what kind of box-shadow you want, you could fake a simple box-shadow effect, directly below the element, using the :after pseudo-selector. Admittedly you might still have to use bg images for your shadow effect, but at least it would separate the BG image from the BG of your main element and keep things less fiddly to update.

Edit: although if it's Quirks Mode, that may not work :-/

So it might be something like:

```
myelement {
    position: relative;
    ...
}

myelement:after {
    display: block;
    width: XXpx;
    height: 5px;
    position: absolute; 
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    content: '';
    background: ...
}
```